# Using multiple awk commands within single line

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

Here is what am trying to do: My data is in sets of rows within same file (the variables vaa vbb are looping over it and am able to control it as required)
What i need is to add an extra column before the data is written to file which is basically a counter that iterates with each set of data.

Eg: Set1 of data row 5-8 , Set2 of data row 14-29, etc

```
Required output:

1,row5 data
1,row6 data
1,row7 data
1,row8 data
2,row14 data
2,row15 data
.
.
.
2,row29 data
.
.
.

====== Code below ======

awk -v vaa=$varAA -v vbb=$varBB -v vcc=$varC 'NR>=vaa&&NR<=vbb' $I >> part_${I%.*}.csv
```

I am writing the file to a csv file. I am able to handle the sets of row and counter variable. But unable to formulate the piece of code which can add the extra column feeding data using the variable $varC (which has the incrementing counter)

I have browsed through several forums and the usage/examples are either simply for printing or just adding a column in existing dataset.

I am new to bash coding so unable to understand how to accomplish this. All help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:
output_A.csv contains data
output_A.txt contains the info regarding what region to what region is the sets of data. (some arithmetic is required which is task specific and i have taken care of) eg of txt file data: 
100 200 xyz
Here is the complete code for reference:

```
for I in 'output_A.csv';
do

varC=0
while read line
do

varC=$(( varC + 1 ))

varA=${line%%,*}
varB=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f2- | rev | cut -d',' -f2- | rev)

varAA=$(echo "$varA * 100" | bc -l)
varBB=$(echo "$varB * 100" | bc -l)

#echo -e $varA ' \t' $varB ' \t' $line

awk -v vaa=$varAA -v vbb=$varBB -v vcc=$varC 'NR>=vaa&&NR<=vbb' $I >> part_${I%.*}.csv

done < ${I%.*}.txt

done
```

Comment: How should one determine when the first set of data has been exhausted and the counter should be increased? Please post a sample of the input file.

Comment: Where in your example are `vaa`, `vbb`, `vcc` ?

Comment: just added the entire code in edits - apologies for missing it out in the first place

Comment: It would be much better if you supply with samples of data files and preferrable output format

Comment: @Costas my doubt is more syntactical in nature. I can figure out the task specific solution. The examples I see are something like: 
awk '{print "$variable name",$0}'

I understand $0 is all columns of the row - How do I relate that to usage of NR controls which in my code controls the range of rows.

Comment: The data in output_A.csv is of format:
0.123,1.234,....(about 200 columns)

The data in output_A.txt is of format: 
11.2345,11.2565,xyz

The data in output_A.txt means 1123-1125 lines are 1 set. (hence the multiplication by 100 to obtain the row number in varAA & varBB

The desired output is:
(set no. eg; 1),0.123,1.234,....(about 200 columns)

Comment: Please, please **[quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/135943).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you need to change your awk command from:

```
'NR>=vaa&&NR<=vbb'
```

to

```
'NR>=vaa&&NR<=vbb { print vcc "," $0 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to format files explanation

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{
               for(i=($1*100),i<=($2*100);i++)
                   portion=FNR
               next }
           { print portion[FNR], $0 }
          ' output_A.txt output_A.csv >> output_A.result
```

Comment: thanks this gives me an idea to improve some parts but my issue is with handling the incremental counter varC which increments with each set of rows.